# How could I go about correcting this JSON code for nested objects

Tags: json, mongodb, nested-object

correcting this JSON code for nested objects
i want correction json

```
{
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Parks",
     "recipe_page":
      {"shortbread":
          "page_visit": [
            "opened_on": ISODate("2020-01-23"),
            "time_opened": "2022-21-03T13:49:51.141Z"
            "time_closed": "2022-21-03T13:59:32.121Z"
          ]
      }
}
```

Comment: The JSON is not a valid one. An array field can have composite types like objects or arrays _or_ scalar values like numbers or strings or boolean. See https://www.json.org/json-en.html

Answer (score 0):

Two things are wrong here:

1. You cannot use ISODate or other functions in a JSON file.
2. You have an array of objects but forgot to wrap each object in curly braces.

See below:

```
{
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Parks",
     "recipe_page":
      {"shortbread":
          "page_visit": [
            {"opened_on": "2020-01-23"},
            {"time_opened": "2022-21-03T13:49:51.141Z"}
            {"time_closed": "2022-21-03T13:59:32.121Z"}
          ]
      }
}
```